# How to display media from any source in MediaElement WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a Video and Audio player using WPF.
MediaElement didn't display audio or video, it is displays nothing actually.

`<MediaElement Name="Player" Grid.Row="1" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Stretch="None" MediaFailed="Player_MediaFailed"/>`

I get, what the problem is with "source", because MediaFailed event is working, so the MediaElement doesn't upload any media resources and I don't now why.

```
 private void Open_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
     openFileDialog.Filter = "Media files (*.mp4;*.mp3;*.mpg;*.mpeg)|*.mp4;*.mp3;*.mpg;*.mpeg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
     if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
         Player.Source = new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName);
 }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.